# Excel VBA On Open Macro Runs for other Workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I have a very simple Workbook_Open procedure that hides the ribbon. Problem is if I have that workbook with the macro open and then open a another different Excel workbook the procedure runs for that workbook and hides its ribbon as well (even for Excel 2003 files)

Any ideas on what is going on? Below is the procedure

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",False)"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer stolen from [this mrexcel topic](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/634090-visual-basic-applications-hide-ribbon-others-how-limit-one-workbook.html).

You need to add `Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate` and `Private Sub Workbook_Activate` to ThisWorkbook as well:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
    Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",False)"
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
    Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro "SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",True)"
End Sub
```

When the new workbook is opened, the previous one will be deactivated, and show the ribbon for the new workbook.

Tested working on Excel 2013